# Overlay filled semi-transparent contours

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to find the contours of an image and overlay them (with some transparency) over another image. However, when I execute the following code I get an undesired effect (see image below).

```
img = cv2.imread('image1.bmp',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

im = cv2.imread('image2.jpg')
im_copy = im.copy()

for j,cont in enumerate(contours): 
    im_copy = cv2.drawContours(im_copy, [cont], -1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    im = cv2.addWeighted(im_copy, 0.4, im, 1 - 0.2, 0)
    im = cv2.drawContours(im, [cont], -1, (0, 0, 255), 0)

cv2.imwrite(f'projects/{prj.name}/logs/repeated_img/{file}', im)
```

[image: Output image]

I call `drawContours()` twice to obtain a semitransparent fill and a solid border. Apparently, one of the contours appears to be more opaque than the other. I suspected that the drawContours is called twice for the same contour, so I tried the following change:

```
    im_copy = cv2.drawContours(im_copy, [cont], j, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    im = cv2.addWeighted(im_copy, 0.4, im, 1 - 0.2, 0)
    im = cv2.drawContours(im, [cont], j, (0, 0, 255), 0)
```

Which produces the following error when trying to draw the second contour:

```
(-215:Assertion failed) 0 <= contourIdx && contourIdx < (int)last in function 'drawContours'
```

Contours will be drawn in different colors depending on some condition, so I need to be able to draw them independently.

What is producing this undesired effect?

---

Edit

Answering the comment, using converting to rbga with the following code

```
im = cv2.imread('image2.jpg')
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
im_copy = im.copy()
    
for j,cont in enumerate(contours): 
    im_copy = cv2.drawContours(im_copy, [cont], -1, (0, 0, 255,128), -1)
    im = cv2.drawContours(im, [cont], -1, (0, 0, 255, 255), 0)
```

Results in the following image:

[image: Output image]

Comment: Try using an alpha channel in your draw color after converting the image to BGRA. `cv2.drawContours(im, [cont], j, (0, 0, 255, 128), 1)` for 50% opacity. Use `cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BRGA)` to change im to BGRA before that. You won't then need to do cv2.addWeighted.

Comment: @fmw42 For some reason, no color is drawn at all this way. I added some extra info above.

Comment: My mistake. That does not work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by addWeight(), as it was called once per contour. This caused some contours to be weighted more than one with the original image, so some regions appeared to be more transparet. I solved the issue in the following way:

```
im = cv2.imread('image1.jpg')                           
im_copy = im.copy()

alpha = 0.5
for cont in contours: 
    if cv2.contourArea(cont) <= 1:
        im_copy = cv2.drawContours(im_copy, [cont], -1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    else:
        im_copy = cv2.drawContours(im_copy, [cont], -1, (51, 197, 255), -1)
filled = cv2.addWeighted(im, alpha, im_copy, 1-alpha, 0)
for cont in contours: 
    if cv2.contourArea(cont) <= 1:
        result = cv2.drawContours(filled, [cont], -1, (0, 0, 255), 0)
    else:
        result = cv2.drawContours(filled, [cont], -1, (51, 197, 255), 0)

cv2.imwrite('result.bmp', result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV. To demonstrate, I will draw a partially transparent red contour on the largest regions. I do this by drawing once in full red on the input and then blending with the original input. I see no way to actually draw partially transparent contours directly.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('scan.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw red filled contour on image background
back = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(back, [big_contour], 0, (0,0,255), -1)

# blend with original image
alpha = 0.25
result = cv2.addWeighted(img, 1-alpha, back, alpha, 0)

# write results
cv2.imwrite('scan_transparent_contour.png', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient implementation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67432417/14851404):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

def draw_contours(
    frame: np.array,
    contours: tuple,
    indices: int = -1, 
    thickness = 1, 
    color: tuple = (0, 0, 255),
    alpha: float = 0.4,
):
    """
    Draw in-place some contours in a frame.
 
    Args:
        frame (np.array): The input frame.
        contours (tuple): The contours defining the mask.
        indices (int): The index of the contours to be drawn.
            Pass ``-1`` to consider all of them.
        color (tuple): The color used to draw the contours.
        alpha (float): A value between ``0.0`` (transparent)
            and ``1.0`` (opaque).
        thickness (int): The thickness of the contours.
    """
    if alpha:
        mask = np.zeros(frame.shape, np.uint8)
        cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, indices, color, -1)
        frame[:] = cv2.addWeighted(mask, alpha, frame, beta=1.0, gamma=0.0)
    cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, indices, color, thickness)
```